# Recursively Parse .text output from selenium into Django model

Tags: python, selenium, parsing

I was able to capture the data I need with selenium python, but I'm wondering how to recursively go through the almost-consistently structured text to create new objects. To get right to the point, selenium output this to a .txt file. Names have been changed to protect the innocent.

```
  (001) DOLE, BOB & ELIZABETH - 1345641
17.23 92.55 22.05 07/24/2007
   (002) FRANKLIN, BENJAMIN - 4005648
88.38 1102.83 1118.32 11/02/2008
(002) CLINTON, WILLIAM & HILLARY - 768568
0.00 288.23 56.00 01/01/1989
    (005) JEFFERSON, THOMAS & MARTHA - 5487784
9230.02 23813.11 555.23 01/04/1780
```

A few hundred lines of that, ranging from 0 to 4 spaces before the (00#). The goal is to result in taking each one and creating a new object with attributes through the django orm. Presumably if I can group every two lines, then I could just run a for loop. I don't need the number in parenthesis so the spaces wouldn't matter, I'd just look for the last name to start one space after the (###).

Any recommendations on how to run through these? The ideal result for every pair of lines would be as follows:

```
entry = Politician.create(
    id = 1345641,
    last_name = 'Dole',
    first_name = 'Bob',
    secondary_first_name = 'Elizabeth',
    amount_one = 17.23,
    amount_two = 92.55,
    amount_three = 22.05,
    favorite_date = parse(07/24/2007)
entry.save()
```

Answer (score 1):

As you suggested I would read two lines at a time:

```
import itertools

with open(fn) as f:
    for two_lines in itertools.zip_longest(f, f, fillvalue=''):
        print(' '.join(two_lines))
```

Output:

```
  (001) DOLE, BOB & ELIZABETH - 1345641 17.23 92.55 22.05 07/24/2007
   (002) FRANKLIN, BENJAMIN - 4005648 88.38 1102.83 1118.32 11/02/2008
(002) CLINTON, WILLIAM & HILLARY - 768568 0.00 288.23 56.00 01/01/1989
    (005) JEFFERSON, THOMAS & MARTHA - 5487784 9230.02 23813.11 555.23 01/04/1780
```

and then regex my way through this...

edit: 
actually I think regex wouldn't even be necessary.

it should be enough to just split up the data like

```
line = ' '.join(two_lines)
line = line.strip()[5:] # remove whitespace and (001)
name, numbers = line.split('-')
id, amount_one, amount_two, amount_three, favorite_date = numbers.split()
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply! So if I skip the writing-to-.txt step and just dump the data into a variable, I could just do `def parse_data(data.text):` and jump straight to the for loop, and in each loop instead of printing, use `joined_lines = (' '.join(two_lines)`, and dump that into `def store_object(joined_lines):` using the code in your last bit there?

Comment: Yeah, that should work... You might want to have a look at the [Grouper Recipe](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes), a variation of that is what I used to get two lines at a time...